# mysql-workbench installation error

Tags: apt, system-installation, software-installation, mysql, mysql-workbench

every time I try to install mysql-workbentch on terminal using the sudo apt install mysql-workbentch command, the following error occurs:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
                             Depends: libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed
                             Depends: libzip5 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am a little new to the ubunto and this problem has already taken a lot of my time, and many unsuccessful attempts. Whoever can help me, I will be forever grateful.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo apt list mysql* --installed`? This will make it possible to identify if you're installing the wrong version of MySQL Workbench for your system.

Comment: When running the code, nothing happens: `$ sudo apt list mysql* --installed` result: 
`Listing... Done`

Comment: That's going to require a bit of work to fix. If you're using Ubuntu Desktop, perhaps you'd prefer [the snap version of MySQL Workbench](https://snapcraft.io/mysql-workbench-community), as this will give you everything you need without having to worry about C libraries ...

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the problem goes beyond that. so I chose to use an alternative similar to the workbench.